# Python adding a string leaves extra characters

Tags: python

If you need any more info just Let Me Know

I have a python script that adds a string after each line on a CSV file. the line `file_lines = [''.join([x.strip(), string_to_add, '\n']) for x in f.readlines()]` is the trouble maker. For each file line it will add the string and then add a new line after each time the string is added.

Here is the script:

```
#Adding .JPG string to the end of each line for the Part Numbers
string_to_add = ".JPG"

#Open the file and join the .JPG to the current lines
with open("PartNums.csv", 'r') as f:
file_lines = [''.join([x.strip(), string_to_add, '\n']) for x in f.readlines()]

#Writes to the file until its done
with open("PartNums.csv", 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(file_lines)
```

The script works and does what it is supposed to, however my issue is later on in this larger script. This script outputs into a CSV file and it looks like this:

```
X00TB0001.JPG
X01BJ0003.JPG
X01BJ0004.JPG
X01BJ0005.JPG
X01BJ0006.JPG
X01BJ0007.JPG
X01BJ0008.JPG
X01BJ0026.JPG
X01BJ0038.JPG
X01BJ0039.JPG
X01BJ0040.JPG
X01BJ0041.JPG
...
X01BJ0050.JPG
X01BJ0058.JPG
X01BJ0059.JPG
X01BJ0060.JPG
X01BJ0061.JPG
X01BJ0170.JPG
X01BJ0178.JPG
```

Without the \n in that line the csv file output looks like this `file_lines = [''.join([x.strip(), string_to_add]) for x in f.readlines()]`:

```
X00TB0001.JPGX01BJ0003.JPGX01BJ0004.JPGX01BJ0005.JPGX01BJ0006.JPG
```

The issue is when I go to read this file later and move files with it using this script:

```
#If the string matches a file name move it to a new directory
dst = r"xxx"

with open('PicsWeHave.txt') as my_file:
    for filename in my_file:
        src = os.path.join(XXX") # .strip() to avoid un-wanted white spaces
        #shutil.copy(src, os.path.join(dst, filename.strip()))
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(src, filename), os.path.join(dst, filename))
```

When I run this whole Script it works until it has to move the files I get this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'XXX\\X15SL0447.JPG\n'
```

I know the file exist however the `'\n'` should not be there and that's why I am asking how can I still get everything on a new line and not have `\n` after each name so when I move the file the strings match.

Thank You For Your Help!

Comment: Why can't you just remove the `\n` from `filename`?

Comment: When I do as I stated then each string is not on a new line and it becomes one line and large block of text

Comment: Don't remove it from the file; remove it from the value you *read* from the file.

Comment: Why can't you remove the \n in the for filename loop? What does print(filename) look like? filename.strip() doesn't work no?  What does print(filename.strip()) show you?

Comment: Can you be more clear when you say remove it from the value you read from

Comment: The filename.strip() worked Thank you

Comment: This `file_lines = [''.join([x.strip(), string_to_add, '\n']) for x in f.readlines()]` looks overly complicated. Why not the much simpler `file_lines = [f'{x.strip()}{string_to_add}\n' for x in f]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As they said above you should use `.strip()`:

```
shutil.copy(os.path.join(src, filename.strip()), os.path.join(dst, filename.strip()))
```

This way it gives you the file name or string you need and then it removes anything else.